# How to programmatically add an item to an ng-select with asynchronous items

Tags: html, angular, typescript

My Angular page has two items of import here. One is a list of skills that are added in by the user and the other is a chart of skills that are acquired based on a job title.
When the user enters a skill into the `ng-select` list it works perfectly. The skill is entered, it goes to the array that is set as the `[(ngModel)]` and everything that requires it runs perfectly. However I want the user to be able to click on a skill in the chart that I mentioned and have it show up on the `ng-select` list as well.

I have tried this before with `ng-select`s that were not populated asynchronously and at that point I was able to add an item to it by doing `.push(...)` on the `[(ngModel)]` item. However possibly because there are is no list of items unless someone is typing in the `ng-select` it will not appear on the page if I do that here. It will still get added to the array, but the next time I type in the `ng-select` the manually added item will be erased.

ng-select:

```
<ng-select 
  class="m-1 ml-2 bg-white d-inline-block" 
  multiple="true" 
  [(ngModel)]="selectedSkills" 
  [items]="skillItems | async" 
  [typeahead]="skillSubject" 
  (change)="populateTitleList()"
  placeholder="Key Skill(s)"
  style="max-width:70%">
</ng-select>
```

Chart:

```
<ngx-charts-bar-horizontal
  [view]="view"
  [scheme]="colorScheme"
  [results]="multi"
  [gradient]="gradient"
  [xAxis]="showXAxis"
  [yAxis]="showYAxis"
  [legend]="showLegend"
  [showXAxisLabel]="showXAxisLabel"
  [showYAxisLabel]="showYAxisLabel"
  [xAxisLabel]="xAxisLabel"
  [yAxisLabel]="yAxisLabel"
  (select)="onSkillBarSelect($event)">
</ngx-charts-bar-horizontal>
```

Creating Items:

```
 this.skillItems = concat(
      observableOf([]),
      this.skillSubject.pipe(
          debounceTime(200),
          distinctUntilChanged(),
          switchMap(text => this.courseService.searchCourseSkills(text, 20).pipe(
              catchError(() => observableOf([])), // empty list on error
              map(skills => skills.map(s => s.name))
          ))
      )
    ).pipe(share());
```

When an item on the chart is clicked:

```
  onSkillBarSelect(event){
    this.courseService.searchCourseSkills(event['name'], 20).subscribe(val => {
      var i:number = 0;
      for(i = 0;i < val.length; i++){
        if(event['name'].toUpperCase() == val[i]['name'].toUpperCase()){
          if(!this.selectedSkills.includes(val[i]['name'])) {
            this.selectedSkills.push(val[i]['name']);
            this.populateTitleList();
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

Populate List:

```
populateTitleList() {
    this.searchParams.keySkills = this.selectedSkills;

    this.suggestedTitleList = [];

    this.skillsService.getJobCloud(this.searchParams).subscribe(data => {
      var i:number = 0;
      for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        if(data['job_names'][i] != undefined)
          this.suggestedTitleList.push(data['job_names'][i], data['job_counts'][i]);
      }
    });
  }
```

The 'Populate List' bit is likely unimportant to the issue but I figured people would ask for it if I didn't include it. The issues is in the `onSkillBarSelect()` function which uses the observable to find a match for the item on the chart that was just selected and if it finds one pushes that value to the `selectedSkills` array which should be controlling what is displayed on the `ng-select` on the page. Yet when an item is clicked and a match is found it is added to the array without showing up on the page.

I'm kind of stumped here, any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it not the `skillItems` Observable which needs to emit a new value?

Comment: To be honest I don't know how to make an observable pointing to an api emit a custom value, though yes it does seems as though the problem is that while the list can be made to include the new custom value the `skillItems` value would read that custom value as invalid.

Comment: You can merge Observables together if you need data from different sources. You could use a Subject for the clickable area, and call its `next()` method with whichever skill gets clicked. You could merge that Subject with another one for the input field's submission.

Comment: Sorry @WillAlexander, but I am unsure what you mean by merging the observables together.

Comment: Check this out: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/merge.html